# I used a permanent 301 redirect and now want to use old domain again, is this bad SEO wise?

Tags: seo, htaccess, 301-redirect

I have a blog that I wanted to professionalize it a bit more and moved from a personalized domain name (`DomainA/subfolder`) to a more professional domain name (`DomainB`).

The blog is from 2015 and I used the personal domain name (`DomainA/subfolder`) until I moved it in 2019 to a different domain name (`DomainB`).

The professionalizing didn't go as planned because I simply didn't have enough time.
Now after 3 years I want to move it back to the personal domain name (`DomainA`).

Back in 2019 I used all 301 permanent redirects from `DomainA/Subfolder` to `DomainB`.

This is what I did:

- Start blog on `domainA.example/subfolder`
- Move blog to `domainB.example`

What I want to do now is:

- Move blog to `DomainA.example` (in root)

So my questions are:

- Is this smart for SEO because I used a permanent 301 redirect?
- I will not be using the subfolder again, so I should be fine using 301 redirect and leave everything as is and create new 301 redirects by step 3?
- And is it allowed when people go to `DomainA/Subfolder` get redirected to `DomainB` and then back to `DomainA`?